# Process termimates after attaching

Tags: memory

I am using ollydbg and whenever i attach ollydbg to running process (in this case it's game and it has xtrap) this game terminates all threads and nothing is shown in olly . And when i use OllyAdvanced and when i attach olly into this proces then olly is stopping execution at ntdll.dll.DbgUiRemoteBreakin. Is there any plugin/way to fix that ?

Comment: "Is there any plugin/way to fix that ?" -- To fix what? Stopping execution at `ntdll.dll!DbgUiRemoteBreakin` is likely by-design.

Comment: I mean to stop in EP not in DbgUiRemoteBreakin.Btw this game has Themida also.

Comment: There's nothing to fix. It's by-design.

Comment: What do you mean?....

Answer (score 1):

See http://index-of.es/Windows/dbgk-2.pdf

TL;DR -- When a debugger (OllyDbg in this scenario) calls [`DebugActiveProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), this results in a call to `DbgUiDebugActiveProcess()`, which calls `DbgUiIssueRemoteBreakin()`, which creates a new thread in the debuggee with entrypoint `DbgUiRemoteBreakin()`.

So there's nothing that needs fixing. What you're seeing is the result of how Windows works.